# Displaying List in TableViewController from array with only 1 item in array

Tags: arrays, xcode, uitableview, swift, ios8

Learning to code Swift, I trying to add an array to a TableView Controller so each item in the array is its own line in the table, all is going well, however if I only have one item in the array, it doesn't show.

```
var myArray = [[""]]
var count = myArray.count
var myArray2 = [""]

for index in 0...count-1 {
    myArray2.append(myArray[index][0])
}
```

In a later func I then add myArray2 to the list, but as I say, it doesn't work if there is only 1 item in the list. Think it is because I am doing 0...count-1, so 0...0, but can't work out another way of doing it.

Thanks

Full Code:

```
import UIKit

struct MyVariables {
static var myArray = [[""]]
}

class HistoryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
var myArray2 = [""]

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
println(MyVariables.myArray)
super.viewDidLoad()

var firstItem = MyVariables.myArray[0][0]
if firstItem == "" {
    MyVariables.myArray.removeAtIndex(0)
}

println(MyVariables.myArray.count)

var count = MyVariables.myArray.count
println(count)
var countIsNotZero = false
println(countIsNotZero)

myArray2.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

if count != 0 {
    countIsNotZero = true
}
println(countIsNotZero)

if count != 0 {
    for index in 0...count-1 {
        myArray2.append(MyVariables.myArray[index][0])
        println(index)
    }
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
println(myArray2.count)
return myArray2.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

println(myArray2.count)
if myArray2.count > 1{
    cell.textLabel?.text = myArray2[indexPath.row]
    println(myArray2.count)
} else {
    cell.textLabel?.text = ""
}
return cell
} 
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me in a playground.  `myArray` has one element. `myArray2` has two elements.  The range `0...0` has one value in it and the for loop will execute once.  Please show your tableView code.

Comment: see below for added code

Comment: In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, this code `if myArray2.count > 1{ ` is keeping your single element from showing.  What were you trying to accomplish with that statement?

Comment: not really sure to say the truth! ill delete it and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table doesn't show a single value because you are filling your label's text with empty string when the array doesn't have at least two items.  If you delete that check, your table will work with one item:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    println(myArray2.count)
    cell.textLabel?.text = myArray2[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```